# Proving equalities with the incircle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

> Prove that if $I$ is the incentre of the triangle $ABC$, then $$AI^2 = bc(s − a)/s.$$

My try:

$sr = (bc)(sinA)/2$ which is similar to the expression above, I equated both of the equalities,

$bc(sinA)/(sr)(2) = bc(s-a)/s(AI^2)$

we only have to prove

$a/s = (s-a)/AI^2$

which I need help proving

Answer (score 1):

We have $${s-a\over AI} = \cos (A/2)$$
and $${r\over AI} = \sin (A/2)$$

so if we multiply those we get $${r(s-a)\over AI^2} = \sin (A/2)\cos (A/2) = \sin A/2$$

Now you can finish.

Comment: =sin(A/2)/2? thx

Comment: no, $( sinA)/2$!

Answer (score 0):

Draw the perpendicular fom I to $AC$
then we have

$$AI^2=r^2+AD^2$$
Now use that

$$r=\frac{A}{s}$$
and $$AD=s-a$$ where $$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$